# Error while opening a local notification using detox

Tags: react-native, detox

I am trying to open a mock local notification using detox, but getting an error.

My code:

```
it('Notif', async () => {
const localNotification = {
  trigger: {
    type: 'push',
  },
  title: 'From push',
  body: 'Body',
  action: 'IDEAS',
  payload: {
    title: 'From push',
    body: 'Body',
    action: 'PROFILE',
  },
};
await device.sendUserNotification(localNotification);
// await device.launchApp({
//   newInstance: true,
//   userNotification: localNotification,
// });
});
```

The test fails with the following error:

```
Test Failed: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x24000000 pkg=com.detoxproj2 (has extras) }

detox[17158] ERROR: [cli.js] Error: Command failed: jest --config e2e/config.json --testNamePattern '^((?!:ios:).)*$' --maxWorkers 1 e2e
```

The commented part in the code also doesn't work as expected, It should open the app through the notification parameters, but it doesn't happen here. Also i don't know if the issue is due to some native android error or so..?

Anyone help...!